# Wicket and Reusable Link

Tags: hyperlink, wicket

'm trying to create a reusable link class that extends Link. I have a webpage with about 7 menu items and I'm using inheritance for my application. I want to create a reusable link class to shorten the length of my code..

As of now the link creates and runs fine when I add(new Link....) as an anonymous class inside oninitialize().

The custom link class (which is an inner class of the base page) works fine when I hard code the instance of the new page to go to, and assign it to a "Page" reference, then pass it into setResponsePage();

The problem is, I'm passing trying to be able to pass object through the constructor generically. When I pass it through the constructor, and try to travel to the new page, I get a session has expired.

I've tried using generics for the class, and I've also tried just declaring a Page reference as a parameter value. Am I supposed to use some sort of Model? Or can someone provide an example of how to do this? I want to be able to use this custom link class to add new links for the 7 menu items, which each have there own class...

Code that works:

```
add(new Link("userPageLink")
{
    public void onClick()
    {
        pageTitle = "User";
        Page next = new UserPage();
        setResponsePage(next);
    }
});
```

Modified code that gives page expired upon click:

```
public class CustomLinkToNewPage extends Link
{
   private String title;
   private Page next;

   public CustomLinkToNewPage(String id, String title, Page newPage) 
   {
      super(id);

      next = newPage; 
      this.title = title; 
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick() 
   {
      SSAPage.pageTitle = title;
      setResponsePage(next);  
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
public class CustomLinkToNewPage<T extends SSAPage> extends Link
```

SSAPage is my base page that extends WebPage... So any object passed in to this class's constructor must extend SSAPage as well.

```
public CustomLinkToNewPage(String id, Class<T> name)
```

Then I passed in the .class reference to the object, and created a new instance of the object using reflection.. then set that instance to Page, and passed it to setResponsePage in my onClick.  Worked nicely, as I couldn't figure out how to do Nicktar's way. So this an alternative in case anyone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that in the first version you crate the Page object when the onClick method of the Link object is called and in the second version, the Page object is created on Page-construction (way earlier).

You might get the result if you pass the Pageclass of the responsepage instead on an instance.

Component features setters for these either with

```
public final <C extends IRequestablePage> void setResponsePage(java.lang.Class<C> cls, PageParameters parameters)
```

or without parameters.

```
public final <C extends IRequestablePage> void setResponsePage(java.lang.Class<C> cls)
```

See [Javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Component.html) for more information.